# How do you add list containing another set of lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a set of lists which contain another set of lists. I just want to add them but I'm not able to since python doesn't allow me. I'm new to python programming and this thing is bugging me from 2 hours though it looks so simple. Here is the list:

```
list = ['60.50', '120', '60', '185', '183.84', '134.50', '369.65', '112.50', '141.54', '141.60', '80', '125', '509.40', '99', '148', '86', '234.40', '135', '81', '97', '395', '193', '185', '261', '72', '157', '138', '90', '101', '72', '125', '116', '106', '118', '123', '128', '107', '81', '204.40', '136', '170.32', '136', '88.50', '114', '76', '125.72']
```

I have already tried a number of ways but still I'm not able to add these values. Please help

Comment: I want to add them all and print the total.

Comment: Have you tried `sum(list)`? I think I don't fully understand your problem

Comment: *"I have a set of lists"* you can't have a `set` of `list`s if that's what you mean. Show the code. Also, the "code" you show doesn't seem to be "a set of lists which contain another set of lists" at all.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. See [ask] for other advice.

Comment: @maury844 I get this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @maury844 What is that supposed to do? If you want to concatenate, use `str.join`. If you want to sum, you'll need to convert the strings to numbers before using `sum`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the way I have questioned it might be wrong, whatever it is; I just wan to add this list and print the total. Can you help?

Comment: @maury844 How do I do that? Convert string to number before using sum? I tried str.join but even that gives error if I try to add them later.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, missed the conversion to number, but that's the first thought that came to my mind, he actually wants to add everything up in the list

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi not without knowing what you are working whit. Add the relevant data. You say you want to do some addition, yet you only show *one* list. It's impossible to answer your question as is.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm working with imaplib here. I just want to do addition with this list data. That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you want to take a list of strings which are decimal numbers, and add them all together.

Rather than using floats for this, I would use `Decimal`. First convert all the items to decimals, then add them.

*(Also don't call it `list`)*

```
from decimal import Decimal

l = [...]
print(sum(Decimal(i) for i in l))
```

---

If the list has multiple dimensions, you'll need to flatten the list first. We can make a function to sum numbers in generic multi-dimensional lists.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def flatten(l):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            yield Decimal(i)
        else:
            yield from flatten(i)

l = [[...], ...]

print(sum(flatten(l))
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Can you help me with this this too if the list is slightly different like this:
list = [['60.50'], ['120'], ['60'], ['185'], ['183.84'], ['134.50'], ['369.65'], ['112.50'], ['141.54'], ['141.60'], ['80'], ['125'], ['509.40'], ['99'], ['148'], ['86'], ['234.40'], ['135'], ['81'], ['97'], ['395'], ['193'], ['185'], ['261'], ['72'], ['157'], ['138'], ['90'], ['101'], ['72'], ['125'], ['116'], ['106'], ['118'], ['123'], ['128'], ['107'], ['81'], ['204.40'], ['136'], ['170.32'], ['136'], ['88.50'], ['114'], ['76'], ['125.72']]

Comment: Can you please help me with this part as well

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to firstly print ur list in form of numpy array ar pandas dataframe and then simply use sum() function... Hope it helps